# API Method not being executed when called from Postman

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm making an API in .NET Framework.

I have a controller called Autos, the API is meant to allow for the registration and retrieval of car models.

At first, I was able to use a GET to fetch an `IEnumerable` instance of List from Postman. I was getting the serialized version of a list I made with dummy data.

However, after I removed the dummy list, changed the method return to `HttpResponseMessage` and switched to a static dictionary I'd be using as a repository, the method stopped being executed upon calling it with Postman. I added logging messages and breakpoints and I can see that they just never execute.

My controller:

```
    public class AutosController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public HttpResponseMessage GetModels(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
//Theres a breakpoint here
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Repository.AutoRepository.Keys);
                return request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Auto>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Repository.AutoRepository.Values);
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public HttpResponseMessage SetModel(HttpRequestMessage request, Auto serializedAuto)
            {
                if (serializedAuto.IsValid())
                {
                    if (Repository.AddToRepository(serializedAuto))
                        return request.CreateResponse<Auto>(HttpStatusCode.Created, Repository.AutoRepository[serializedAuto.Id]);
                    else
                        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                } else
                {
                    return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
        }
```

And my API Route

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

I can successfully use SetModel and I can confirm that the sent model is also added to the repository. I am also able to return it to postman.

The postman address I'm using for the GET is

```
localhost:51020/api/v1/GetModels
```

Comment: I am wondering how you use HttpRequestMessage as a "request" input parameter in Postman? Can you please explain, or post the picture? I see "request".CreateResponse?

Comment: I added that later, but it was still not working without it.

Comment: Why do you added it? request is a whole class instance that has methods. Can you post it pls?  We can' t help without it .  I especially wondering about request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Auto>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Repository.AutoRepository.Values);

Comment: I added it because I need a way to send a 404 if the dictionary is empty. I did not create the HttpRequestMessage class, it is part of net framework
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-5.0

But as I said, this is not the cause of the problem, since it still doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i see it, your action could be

```
 [Route("~/api/v1/GetModels")]
public IEnumerable<Auto> GetModels()
  {

    var values = Repository.AutoRepository.Values;
    if (values==null) throw new HttpException(404, "Some description");
    return values;

}
```

Comment: But is this related to the fact that the action is not being called? (I cant test it atm)

Comment: @Dasph action is usually not being called because of  bad routing. Add attribute route as it in my answer, and try again